# Create Project within Jira Service Management with API Call - wrong data <Response 400>

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, rest, jira-rest-api

With the rest-api curl out of the terminal (mac) its working properly:

```
curl -X POST \       
https://atc-{url}.net/sd/rest/api/2/project \
-H 'Authorization: Basic *******************' \ 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
-d '{
"key": "TEST",
"name": "TEST Project",
"projectTypeKey": "service_desk",
"projectTemplateKey": "com.atlassian.servicedesk:basic-service-desk-project",
"description": "Example Project description",
"lead": "Username",
"assigneeType": "PROJECT_LEAD",
"avatarId": 10200
}'
```

A project is getting created in my Jira instance. In my Python Script on the other hand im using the `requests` library. All the time I'm receiving an 400 Error Response but I've tried various headers and data inputs but it allways returns 400.... Code is looking like this:

```
headers = {
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ********************'
}

data = {'key': 'TEST',
        'name': 'test_project',
        'projectTypeKey': 'service_desk',
        'projectTemplateKey': 'com.atlassian.servicedesk:basic-service-desk-project',
        'description': 'description',
        'lead': 'NAME',
        'assigneeType': 'PROJECT_LEAD',
        'avatarId': 10200
        }

try:
    log.info("try to start curl for {} creation".format(project_key,))
    res = requests.post(
        'https://atc-{url}/sd/rest/api/2/project', headers=headers, data=data)
    log.info(res)
    project_created = True

    if res.status_code == 500:
        project_created = False

except:
    project_created = False
    log.info("curl failed")
```

I think my data part is corrupt...

Comment: are you posting `data` or `json`?  try and update 1 line:     `res = requests.post('https://atc-{url}/sd/rest/api/2/project', headers=headers, json=data)`   - possibly rename your `data` object too to remove confusion

Comment: perfect, that works! ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `data=data` to `json=data` and now it works.